# How can geom_path and geom_point colors be changed separately so they are reflected in the legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

If I have two datasets, and want to plot them as points with a line through them. I can very simply do that with code like this.

```
library(ggplot2)

xdata = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
ydata = xdata^2
ydata2 = 2^xdata
xydata = data.frame(xdata,ydata)

ggplot(xydata) +
  geom_path(aes(x=xdata,y=ydata,color="x^2"),size=1) +
  geom_point(aes(x=xdata,y=ydata,color="x^2"),size=2) +
  geom_path(aes(x=xdata,y=ydata2,color="2^x"),size=1) +
  geom_point(aes(x=xdata,y=ydata2,color="2^x"),size=2)
```

Which results in [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MmwL.png). The legend correctly shows the point and path, as well as their colors.
Now, I want to change the lines and points separately, and have those changes reflected in the legend. I am not sure how to do this though. If I try naively changing the linetype for a path and color for a point, those changes are not carried over to the legend.

```
library(ggplot2)

xdata = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
ydata = xdata^2
ydata2 = 2^xdata
xydata = data.frame(xdata,ydata)

ggplot(xydata) +
  geom_path(aes(x=xdata,y=ydata,color="x^2"),size=1) +
  geom_point(aes(x=xdata,y=ydata,color="x^2"),size=2,color="black") +
  geom_path(aes(x=xdata,y=ydata2,color="2^x"),size=1,linetype="dashed") +
  geom_point(aes(x=xdata,y=ydata2,color="2^x"),size=2)
```

Resulting in [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnec2.png). I understand why this is the case, but I do not know a good way (meaning general/clean way) to fix the legend to match the geom_point and geom_line. Which would look [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDN8x.png).

I am hoping there is a quick way to do this, or at least a straightforward way. I have tried messing around with aes(fill), scale_color_manual, scale_linetype_manual, and melting the data, but have been unable to get what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky since ggplot2 uses "color" to control both geom_line colors and geom_point colors, so I don't know a straightforward way to mix them and have the legend reflect that.

A hack that works here is to use a geom_point shape with fill (e.g. 21) and use "fill" instead. To make the color and fill legends combine, we need to give them the same name. To make the black for one line, we can use `scale_fill_manual` and specify the two point colors.

```
ggplot(xydata) +
  geom_path(aes(x=xdata,y=ydata,color="x^2"),size=1) +
  geom_point(aes(x=xdata,y=ydata,color="x^2", fill="x^2"), shape = 21, size = 3, stroke = 0) +
  geom_path(aes(x=xdata,y=ydata2,color="2^x"),size=1,linetype="dashed") +
  geom_point(aes(x=xdata,y=ydata2,color="2^x", fill = "2^x"), shape = 21, size=3, stroke = 0) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "group") +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "group", values = c("#F8766D", "black"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, combined with Gregory's answer this does what I want,. Although I guess I am limited to the point shapes that can be filled.

Answer (score 0):

Legends in ggplot2 reflect how visual qualities (e.g. color, linetype) are mapped to data, so its easier if there is data that can answer the question "what color should this be?", for example. For this reason, it works better to have all the "y" data in one long column, and have another column that explains which group each value belongs to so that color and linetype can be mapped to that column.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
xdata = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)

df <- data.frame(x = rep(xdata, 2),
                 y = c(xdata^2, 2^xdata),
                 func = factor(rep(c("x^2", "2^x"), each = 6))) %>%
  group_by(func)
df
#> # A tibble: 12 × 3
#> # Groups:   func [2]
#>        x     y func 
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <fct>
#>  1     1     1 x^2  
#>  2     2     4 x^2  
#>  3     3     9 x^2  
#>  4     4    16 x^2  
#>  5     5    25 x^2  
#>  6     6    36 x^2  
#>  7     1     2 2^x  
#>  8     2     4 2^x  
#>  9     3     8 2^x  
#> 10     4    16 2^x  
#> 11     5    32 2^x  
#> 12     6    64 2^x

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = func, linetype = func)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_path() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "black"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this combined with Jon Spring's answer got me what I wanted. As far as I can tell, there still isn't a good way to mix point and line colors using just this approach though.